# How to req.query in Prisma?

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma

I am having some trouble with req.query in my nextjs dynamic API route.

The following code works where `id` is fixed (in this case "2")

```
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma"

export default async function handler (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        try {
            const data = await prisma.product.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: 2
                }
            })
            return res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(data));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({msg: 'Something went wrong in fetching id query - error 500'});
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(405).json({ msg: 'Method not allowed - error 405' });
    }
}
```

This would perform a GET request and I would receive this successfully:
[image]

However, what I want is to perform this GET request dynamically. But, if I changed the `id` with `req.query.id` so that I can GET individual request on the server based on the id parameter, it throws an error 500.

Any hints as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved - the query requires to be parsed before being read. The solution is to provide `const id = JSON.parse(req.query.id)` and the pass the `id` into `where { id: id }`.